# How can I set up an alert to send an email when someone does a vip swap in azure

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, alerts

I have several individuals across multiple organizations that would like to know when a change has been made to our azure platforms. They only connect through the production environment.

I would like to set up an email alert that goes out when a Virtual IP swap has been performed but it does not seem to be an option in the cloud alert services.

Is there something I am missing or another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe there is anyway to do this without custom coding.

Edit thanks to kwill's correct responses:

1) You can install something on the Webrole that would periodically check RoleEnvironment.CurrentInstance.

```
var roleInstance = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance; 
foreach (RoleInstanceEndpoint instanceEndpoint in roleInstance.InstanceEndpoints.Values) 
{  
   Trace.WriteLine("Instance endpoint address and port: " + instanceEndpoint.IPEndpoint, "Information");
   Trace.WriteLine("Protocol for the endpoint: " + , instanceEndpoint.Protocol, "Information");
}
```

2) You can create a custom application that would use Service Management API to get at the RoleInstance object from the "outside" by using management certificates and navigating the hierarchy of services, roles, etc.  If using Visual Studio/.NET here's a library to help you get started: http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.windowsazure.management.libraries

Comment: Your main answer that it isn't possible without some custom code is correct, but the IP address of your app.cloudapp.net URL will not change with a VIP swap.  There are a couple ways to do this:

Comment: 1) Periodically call out to something like www.whatismyip.com from within the Azure VMs.  Once that value changes then you know a VIP swap has occurred.  or  
2) Periodically call the Service Management API to see what is deployed in each slot of your hosted service.  This is the easier and more reliable option.